# how to set a variable for application scope i.e. only 1 for entire application in grails controller

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

i want to set one variable for my entire application and i want to update it whenever a request comes in to a particular action

like

```
def action = {
    // some integer variable is already set in application scope with name variable
    variable++
    render(view:"action", model:[variable])
}
```

In Gsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        Variable is ${variable}
    </body>
</html>
```

The output would be

Variable is 1
// on subsequent requests
Variable is 2
and so on....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it needs to be one across whole app?

Its possible by using an (singleton) service, that will handle your value, like:

```
class VariableService {
   int value

   synchronized int get() {
      return value
   }

   synchronized int inc(int value) {
      this.value += value
      return this.value   
   }

   synchronized void set(int value) {
      this.value = value
   }
}
```

and the use it where you need

Answer (score 2):

for this use case there are some opportunities:

- store your var in http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/servletContext.html (there is a method called setAttribute)
- create you own bean with singleton-scope to store you vars
- i suppose you don't want to do that, but you can also use the database

Don't increment your 'global' var in every controller action, use a filter instead.